# What is the HTTP network flow used by Firestore JS SDK?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We use heavily Firebase JS SDK, and at one point encountered an issue where updates made by the SDK (using `updateDoc`) did not reach the server (though no network issues were detected). Same happened also for `onSnapshot` call (no updates retrieved from server, although there were updated).
In order to better understand what happens, we wanted to understand what happens on the network layer (in terms of HTTP requests flow), especially when we listen for updates, or perform updates.

The question is created in order to share our findings with other who are wondering about this, and in case some one from the Firebase team can confirm.

We performed `updateDoc` and `onSnapshot` calls using Firebase JS SDK for Firestore, and expected to be able to associate the network requests seen in Chrome Dev Tools to these SDK calls.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the observations regarding the HTTP calls flow.

When we initialize Firestore, a Web Channel is created on which the traffic between the client and the server will go through.

The Web Channel uses gRPC over HTTP/2 (thanks [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) for the tip)

The default behavior is as follows:

1. Commands (e.g. start listen, set data) are sent using POST requests.
2. The response includes SID, which identifies the command lifecycle. Note that start listen commands (on different docs) will share the same SID.
3. SSE-based (server-side-events) GET requests with ±1 minute interval are used to listen on results from the commands (with the appropriate SID).
4. After the interval ends, a new SSE-based GET request will be created unless the command finished (e.g. stop listen was called, data was set).
5. If the command finished, and no additional GET request is required, a POST terminate request will be sent with the relevant SID.

The listen (`onSnapshot`) behavior by default is as follows:

1. Whenever `onSnapshot` is called, we have a POST request to a LISTEN endpoint to addTarget which returns immediately with SID. The addTarget includes the document path and a targetId generated by the client for later use. If there's already an open onSnapshot, it will use the same SID.
2. Following the POST response, a pending GET request is created which receives changes. It will use the same SID.
3. The pending GET requests receives changes are for all target (listened) objects (e.g. documents).
4. The GET request remains open for about a minute (sometimes less, sometimes more).
5. Every time new data arrives, it is processed, but the GET request remains open until it's interval (±1 minute) has passed.
6. The GET request also receives the initial values once a target was added (via onSnapshot).
7. Once the interval has passed, the pending GET request ends (and we can see the response).
8. Once it ends, it is replaced by a new pending GET request, which behaves the same way.
9. Whenever we unsubscribe from a listener, there is a POST request to a LISTEN endpoint to removeTarget.
10. After unsubscribing from all targets, the GET request will still end after the interval completes. However, no new GET request will initiate, and a terminate POST request will be sent.

Setting data for a doc (`setDoc`) behaves as follows:

1. A POST request is sent to the backend in order to start a session and receive SID.
2. A pending GET request is created, on which we aim to receive updates when the data was set in the backend. The pending GET request leaves for ±1 minute.
3. Another POST request is created with the update details (e.g. update field f1  on document d1 ).
4. Once the Firestore backend has updated the data, we'll receive the update operation details on the GET request, which will remain pending until the ±1 minute interval completes.
5. After the interval completes, and if the data was stored in the backend DB, the GET request will end, and a terminate POST request will be sent.

With long-polling (set by [experimentalForceLongPolling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Settings#optional-experimentalforcelongpolling)) we have the following notable changes:

1. Every time there's a change in an object we listen on, the pending GET request is ended and a new one is created instead.
2. Instead of ±1 minute GET request, we have a ±30 seconds GET request followed by a ±15 seconds GET request.